# Define a list of words and check whether any of those words exist in the body of text

Tags: python-3.x

can you please help me with the logic of the following questions. I would like to define a list of different words and check if the words exist in the text, if so I would like the word return, if the words are not part of the text, I would like a message to be returned.

The code I have is the following:

```
def search_word():
with open('testing.txt', 'r') as textFile:
    word_list = ['account', 'earn', 'free', 'links', 'click', 'cash', 'extra', 'win', 'bonus', 'card']
    for line in textFile.read():
        for word in word_list:
            if word in line:
                print(word)
            else:
                print('The text does not include any predefined words.')
```

`search_word()`

The output I get is the else statement. I know the issue is with the "for line in textFile.read()" code, however I am trying to understand why the logic does not work in the above code.

I get the right result by change to the following code by moving the "fileText = textObjet.read()" before the for loop command.

```
def search_word():
with open('email.txt', 'r') as textObject:
    fileText = textObject.read()
    word_list = ['account', 'earn', 'free', 'links', 'click', 'cash', 'Extra', 'win', 'bonus', 'card']
    for word in word_list:
        if word in fileText:
            print(word)
        else:
            print(word, '- the email does not include any predefined spam words.')
```

search_word()

I would appreciate your help with understanding the difference in the logic.

thanks.

Lois

Answer (score 0):

Assume the testing.txt contain only one word `account`, `read()` return your text file as a string like `'account\n'`.

`for line in textFile.read():` is reading every character (including space and new line) in that string, something like `['a', 'c', 'c', 'o', 'u', 'n', 't', '\n']`, then
`for word in word_list:` compare words in word_list to every character. 10 words to 'a', then 10 words to 'c' ... and at last 10 words to \n. Not a single word comparison is match so we will have 80 (10 words x 8 characters) else statement executed.

While using `fileText = textObject.read()` without a for loop, `for word in word_list:` just compare words in word_list to that string. 'account' to 'account\n', 'earn' to 'account\n' ... 'card' to 'account\n'. This time return only 10 results for 10 words you have.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. That makes it easier.